# Why is FF3 rendering an <h3> inside an <a> incorrectly?

Tags: css, firefox

Take a look at [this page](http://www.larsonsystems.com/products/index.php) in FireFox. Feel free to navigate to any of the top six product categories to see more of the same type of code.

If you are [un]lucky enough to see the glitch, you will see at least one product box expand it's height to epic proportions.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="product_category">
  <a href="../products/dht_1500.php" style="height: 340px;">
    <h3>DHT 1500</h3>
    (superfluous HTML omitted here)
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is what Firebug reveals:

```
<div class="product_category">
  <a style="height: 340px;" href="../products/dht_1500.php"> </a>
    <h3><a _moz-rs-heading="" style="height: 340px;" href="../products/dht_1500.php">DHT 1500</a></h3>
    (superfluous HTML omitted here)
  <a style="height: 340px;" href="../products/dht_1500.php"> </a>
</div>
```

You can see FireFox is definitely closing my  tags and re-opening them again, and pulling the custom CSS height style along with it, which is resulting in each product box height skyrocketing.  Also note that strange *_moz-rs-heading=""* bit.

I suspect my problem has to do with my using block HTML elements within an inline  tag, but I thought I solved that problem by converting the  tags to block formatting in my stylesheet:

```
.product_category a {
    display: block;
}
```

FireFox is playing favorites to my  tags.  It usually renders the page like I want it, but then every once-in-a-while, it will blow one of my product boxes sky-high, and seemingly at random.

The pages work properly in Internet Explorer and Safari.  I have been testing it with FireFox 3.6 on Mac, but have seen the same problem on FireFox for PC.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having block level elements (h3) inside an inline element (a) is not valid HTML.

Change your block elements to a span and use CSS to style it how you wish.

Comment: Just to add onto what hobodave said, this is true whether you've changed the display of the elements in your stylesheet or not.

Comment: Yeah… that is definitely what's going on.  I've converted my <h3> and <p> tags into spans and they don't confuse FireFox anymore.  Now what to do with my <ul> tags?  I'd hate to revert to manually typing in my bullets but at this point I don't see any alternative (short of completely re-tooling my enclosing <a> tags).

Thanks for the very fast feedback guys; this is a cool site.

Comment: @HazMatt: Ask a new question, this one is answered. :)

Answer (score 2):

[**A similar question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292920/what-could-cause-this-html-css-rendering-issue-in-firefox/2292971#2292971) with the exact same symptoms was asked a few days back. The solution there was in fact taking the native block elements out of the natively inline ones. Seems changing `display` doesn't help in this case.